# Using Matlab functions in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I have a lot of Matlab functions that I need to use in Python. I'm trying to translate them, but it is too hard since I barely know Matlab and I'm still learning Python. Is there a way I can use these functions without translating them?

Comment: In particular, I would ignore the accepted answer of the duplicate target and look at the other answers. Apparently, Mathworks provides bindings. See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html)

Comment: do you have to pay to get that package?

Comment: I do not know. I assume you already have a Matlab license? Probably that is sufficient.

Comment: no I don't! that is why I use Python...